# Django Rest Framework override viewset list() method without loosing filter_backends functionality

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a viewset and I override `list()` method, but filtering by field stop working. How can I call filtering options from my code:

This is my viewset:

```
 class SupplementViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = models.Product.objects.filter()
    serializer_class = serializers.SuplementSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter, OrderingFilter,)
    search_fields = ('hotel', 'name')
    filter_fields = ('id', 'hotel', 'name')

    def perform_create(self, instance):
        instance.save(product_type=models.Product.SUPPLEMENT)

    def list(self, request, pk=None):
        if pk == None:
            supplements = models.Product.objects.filter(product_type=models.Product.SUPPLEMENT)
        else:
            supplements =  models.Product.objects.get(product_type=models.Product.SUPPLEMENT, id=pk)

        page = self.paginate_queryset(supplements)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        result_set = serializer.data

        return Response(result_set)

    def get_result_set(self, supplements):
        result_set = serializers.ProductSerializer(supplements, many=True).data

        return result_set
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
def list(self, request, pk=None):
    if pk == None:
        supplements = models.Product.objects.filter(product_type=models.Product.SUPPLEMENT)
    else:
        supplements =  models.Product.objects.filter(product_type=models.Product.SUPPLEMENT, id=pk)

    supplements= self.filter_queryset(supplements)
    page = self.paginate_queryset(supplements)
```

`self.filter_queryset(queryset)` is what you need, but it must accept queryset.

Answer (score 3):

It would be helpful to see the actual implementation of the list method:

http://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.viewsets/ReadOnlyModelViewSet.html#list

You can directly use the `self.filter_queryset` method (which is inherited from `GenericAPIView` in `viewsets.ModelViewSet`). In very rare scenarios you will need to override the `self.filter_queryset` method.

Answer (score 0):

Both Ykh and Akshay Anurag answers are correct, for sake of simplicity you could simply call:

```
filter_queryset(queryset)
```

before calling

```
paginate_queryset(filtered_queryset)
```